# How to link two relational tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, database-schema

I have two tables

1. Video (v_id, v_duration, v_status, upload_date) in the video table the primary key is v_id.
2. video_tags(tag_name, video_id)

The video can have many tags, that's why I separated them into two tables. The question is when I create these two tables using mySQL database, I managed to create the first table using the below sql statement,
create table video (v_id int, v_duration double, v_status varchar(50) default 'needs approval', upload_date DATE, primary key(v_id))

but the second I couldn't because of misunderstanding of the reference keys.

Is this mySQL statement true?

create table video_tags(tag_name varchar(50), video_id int, primary key(vidoe_id, tag_name))

Comment: Why I can't use video_id as a foreign key and tag_name as a primary key? I know its conceptual question, but I hope to get a reasonable answer for it @helloworld

Comment: your answer doesn't add any relation between the first and second table, they become disconnected !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE `video_tags` (
`tag_id` INT NOT NULL,
`tag_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`video_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
 INDEX `video_id` (`video_id` ASC),
 INDEX `tag_name` (`tag_name` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `video_id_fk`
 FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`)
 REFERENCES  `video` (`v_id`))
```

Use another column as primary key

Comment: Why I can't use video_id as a foreign key and tag_name as a primary key? I know its conceptual question, but I hope to get a reasonable answer for it @helloworld

Comment: That should work. Your code was not defining a relationship. You were only creating 2 indexes.

Comment: The tag_name can't be alone as a primary key, because it can repeat for more than one video id.
example: 

(tag_name, video_id) ==>
(Education, 123)
(Community, 123)
(Education, 155)

Comment: Just use another column as a primary id and set video id as an index with reference to video table. I updated the answer to reflect the change.